# I have 2 network interfaces in an Ubuntu 20.04 build, how can I force SMB/CIFS connections over the secondary network interface?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mount, smb, cifs

As the title says, I have 2 network interfaces in an Ubuntu 20.04 build - 1 1GbE link for internet etc. and a secondary 10GbE link that is directly connected to a file server. The 10GbE link has been manually configured on both ends and I can confirm I'm able to ping across the link using the -I flag to specify the 10GbE interface.

I'm attempting to mount shares from the file server via /etc/fstab but getting error 115 which I believe is due to CIFS/SMB trying to use the 1GbE link to establish the share mount.

Is there a way to specify the secondary 10GbE link should be used to negotiate the mount?

Answer (score 1):

Quadruple check your work kids, this issue was entirely the fault of a typo I made in my /etc/fstab file

Answer (score 0):

Set another Subnet for the two 10GbE-Nics. So your 1GbE-Link won't talk to then as it doesn't know how.

Like that..

Computer

- 1 GbE - DHCP
- 10GbE - 172.16.10.5/24  MTU9000

Server

- 1 GbE - DHCP
- 10GbE - 172.16.10.10/24 MTU9000

If the Server has only the one NIC, you could just assign a Second IP to it. `ifconfig eth0:0 172.16.10.10/24`

Computer:
/etc/fstab
172.16.10.10:/mnt/point ....

Comment: I should have been more specific, both have to be static and are on their own subnets:
- 1GbE = 10.0.0.x
- 10GbE= 10.0.1.x

Comment: And you are using the IP for Mount?  / The Server listens even on the device.  smb.conf bind / bind interfaces only

Comment: As humiliating as it is to share and despite generally being a staunch triple checker, I absolutely borked my fstab file and this issue was entirely my fault.